# Writing vectorized function with lubridate::month() to produce fiscal year

Tags: r, vectorization, lubridate

I'm writing a function to take a date and output the (June 30) fiscal year month, where July is FY month 1, August is 2, and June is 12.

For instance, given two years of dates, I expect the output from this data to be `c(1:12, 1:12)`:

```
data.frame(perf_dt = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-07-01"),
                              to   = as.Date("2021-06-01"),
                              by   = "month"))
```

My current function is this. It includes logic to optionally allow output of labels.

```
FY_mo <- function(date, label = F, abbrev = F) {
  a <- (5 + (lubridate::month(date) %% 12)) + 1
  CY_num = lubridate::month(date)
  ifelse(!label, a,
          ifelse(abbrev,
                  month.abb[CY_num],
                  month.name[CY_num]))
}
```

This works when I feed it individual dates. For instance, this test from `testthat` passes:

```
test_that("FY_mo works on indiv input dates", {
  expect_equal(7, FY_mo(as.Date("2020-01-01")))
  expect_equal("January", FY_mo(as.Date("2020-01-01"), label = TRUE))
  expect_equal("Jan", FY_mo(as.Date("2020-01-01"), label = TRUE, abbrev = TRUE))
})
```

But it doesn't work when I feed it a vector. The code below outputs all "13".

```
data.frame(perf_dt = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-07-01"),
                                             to =   as.Date("2021-06-01"),
                                             by = "month")) %>%
                 dplyr::mutate(FY_mo = FY_mo(perf_dt)) %>%
                 dplyr::pull(FY_mo)
#[1] 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

Where's my mistake? Is there a better way to structure the function to produce the right output for vectors?

Comment: or just use `Vectorize`: `FY_mo <- Vectorize(FY_mo)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a mistake as such but since we are using `ifelse` to check the condition here and `ifelse` returns a vector of the same length as `test`. As our `test` is of length 1 (`length(!label)`) it returns only 1 st value and recycles it. Here since we have a single condition to check we can use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse` which will avoid this issue.

```
FY_mo <- function(date, label = F, abbrev = F) {
  a <- match(lubridate::month(date), c(7:12, 1:6))
  CY_num = lubridate::month(date)
  if(!label) a
  else if (abbrev) month.abb[CY_num]
       else month.name[CY_num]       
}

data.frame(perf_dt = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-07-01"),
                              to =   as.Date("2021-06-01"),
                              by = "month")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(FY_mo = FY_mo(perf_dt)) %>%
  dplyr::pull(FY_mo)

#[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Thank you. Desired output is `c(1:12, 1:12)`. I'll take another look.

Comment: @JonSpring I see. I guess logic in this line needs to be changed `a <- (5 + (lubridate::month(date) %% 12)) + 1`

Comment: Thanks! I changed to `a <- ((5 + lubridate::month(date)) %% 12) + 1` and that worked.